# SharePoint 2013 - Unique permissions for claims

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, security, claims, csom

This is about SharePoint 2013 On-Premise environment. We've a scenario in which certain content is authored in source site collection and published to a target site collection via **cross-site publishing**. The content developed is targeted for certain group of users in **AD** and country claim type.

We are approaching to use **remote event receiver** to assign item level permissions to the list in which content is stored. Problem is, the list will have content migrated from another source which has about ~7000 items as of today. If we are breaking permissions on each of them it will be around - **7000 * 5 AD groups * min. 5 countries = 1,75,000 unique permissions**. SharePoint has a limit of 50,000 unique permissions per list/library.

Even if we restrict limit of AD groups and countries, the solution doesn't look scalable.

Any thoughts on what other approaches we can take to achieve item level permissions or authorization so that published articles are viewed by only people in those AD groups or with country claim.
Also still not able to figure out how to give permissions for claim type from CSOM. Some ideas anyone?

Comment: Remote event receivers are applicable **ONLY** to SP Online.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using Folders?

That 50k limit is just a recommendation because performance starts to plummet after that point, but the limit refers specifically to unique permissions *per container*.

Therefore you could divvy up the items into folders, and your solution will still remain performant. You would simply just apply the permissions to the folders and not the items themselves.

Comment: Hi James, I do have considered folders as an approach.With folders have resolved 1 prob. However, 2nd issue still remains as to how to associate security with Countries. Each item being created is meant for some target country. I can't break down country wise folders because its a multi-selection field, unnecessary I'll have duplicate items in folders. If I break permissions on country claims, I immediately run into bad performance issues. If I don't and use it for information hiding, and create custom web parts to show relevant information, not sure how to write query for filtering by claims.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to use permissions to route your content to target your users? If not you can maybe use content by search webpart with query parameters to filter articles on users country in their profile? We have just done the same for an intranet for 18,000 users, targeting content based on location and organization.

Comment: Hi Petter, Yes we are finally using a hybrid approach, the content was targeted for multiple level of permissions, I reduced the breaks for the content specific for permissions by using folders. The remaining like country is being targeted as information hiding. I'll configure search webparts to query and filter. Problem is however, the country is coming as claims with the user, not in their profile. Either we sync the claims with profile or some other approach need to check yet.

Comment: Did you do targeting with user profile properties? Can you share example?